# EF Core - navigation property without existing key in related table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to create a navigation property in EF Core without having key in the related table?

My idea is to store information to a couple of modules but not for all. So the module-table will not store all keys which are related to the other table.

```
public class Subscription : ISubscription
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// FullName of module
        /// </summary>
        public string ModuleId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Startdate when the module is activated
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime SubStartUTC { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Enddate when the module is deactivated (default: DateTime.MaxValue)
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime SubEndUTC { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedUTC { get; set; }

        public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

        // if I uncomment this, the relation will be created 
        // and an error occurs because some keys a not 
        // in related table
        //public virtual Module Module { get; set; }
}

public class Module
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; } 
}
```

In my module table are only rows for a kind of modules. In the `subscription` table are a lot of `moduleId` which are not in the `module` table. I would like to create a navigation property in the `subscription` table and map them only if a key exists in the `module` table.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you add your entity classes and clarify?

Comment: I added more informations. Hope it helps to understand my problem.

Comment: Code first or DB first?

Comment: When a `Subscription`, with `ModuleId` which are not in the `module` table, is loaded, do you need to get the `ModuleId` value?

Comment: No, only if ModuleId exists in Module table. I'm using DB first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[NotMapped]` attribute in your model to include the Module property but not as a foreign key.

```
public class Subscription : ISubscription
{

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// FullName of module
        /// </summary>
        public string ModuleId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Startdate when the module is activated
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime SubStartUTC { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Enddate when the module is deactivated (default: DateTime.MaxValue)
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime SubEndUTC { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedUTC { get; set; }

        public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public virtual Module Module { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will have to do a "manual" left join to get the related data for modules. You have to do a left join to get data from the Modules table if there is a matching ModuleId or leave the Module property null if there are no matches.

```
from subscription in _yourDbContext.Subscriptions
join module in _yourDbContext.Modules
on subscription.ModuleId equals module.Id into moduleJoin
from module in moduleJoin.DefaultIfEmpty() // this makes it a left join
select new Subscription
{
    Id = subscription.Id,
    TenantId = subscription.TenantId
    ModuleId = subscription.ModuleId,
    Module = module
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My hope is to find a extension method for doing all that stuff behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

With the model :

```cs
public class Subscription
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public string ModuleId { get; set; }
    public Module Module { get; set; }
}
```

As the foreign key property OR the navigation property aren't nullable, EF consider the relation as required. Then the include is translated to SQL query with `inner join` :

```sql
select *
from Subscriptions as s
inner join Modules as m on m.Id = s.ModuleId
```

So, only subscriptions with existing module are returned.

---

To obtain additional subscriptions (with not existing module), you need to declare the relation no required, then include will be translated to SQL query with `left join` :

```sql
select *
from Subscriptions as s
inner join Modules as m on m.Id = s.ModuleId
```

To do this, you cant declare the foreign key property and the navigation property as nullable :

```cs
public class Subscription
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public string? ModuleId { get; set; }
    public Module? Module { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want modify the entity, you can use the fluent syntax :

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Module>()
        .WithMany<Subscription>()
        .WithOne(s => s.Module)
        .HasForeignKey<Subscription>(s => s.ModuleId)
        .IsRequired(false);
}
```